# Overloading and recursion

Tags: recursion, overloading

I've been doing problems on recursion in my Data Structures & Algorithms class and for some tail-recursive functions I couldn't think of doing anything but having the main function call a helper function and the helper function being the tail recursive part since I had to pass different parameters than the original function.

While this is technically tail-recursive the original function is the one that ends up handling the base cases and in the main case passes the additional parameters to the actual tail recursive function.

Obviously this sort of defeats the idea of recursion, especially in a class setting for homework, exams and such.

That's why today I thought, instead of making a helper function, couldn't I make an overloaded version of the function that accepts those additional parameters and continues the work? It would technically be recursive since all the calls in the function are to itself, albeit with more parameters than the initial call.

Here's a rough example:

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n, 2, 1, 2);
}

int fibonacci(int n, int f1, int f2, int c) {
    if (c == n)
        return f1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n, f1 + f2, f1, c + 1);
}
```

Is it still recursion in the definition sense? Would it work? Would the compilers that do recursion optimization (don't know how it works exactly, but know it exists) apply that to this?

I assume that it's still recursion since it's technically calling itself still and I would think it would optimize, just ignoring the initial call. But that's why I'm asking, to see if I'm right or not.

Comment: As an aside, you made a mistake that is very common for people writing recursive functions: you forgot to `return` the value of the function call (e.g. `return fibonacci(...)`).

Comment: Just fixed that, which is odd since the program still ran and output the answer when I did cout << fibonacci(n)

Comment: yeah, that's probably because the last function call returns `f1` from `fibonacci(int, int, int, int)` which is the desired fibonacci number (so it's stored in the eax register if you're on x86), and the `return`s should propogate that upwards but they don't, but since there are no `return`s, the last function call's value isn't overwritten so it just happens to work. But it won't always work on all architectures and it's technically invalid C++ because "not all paths return a value" which your compiler should warn you about.

Comment: This is the "standard" way to handle fibonacci recursively. The overloading is irrelevant as the names could be completely random, and still have the desired semantics (even if it would be considered "bad code") -- in a statically typed language with overloading the type signature *is* part of the "name". While the "prep" function is *itself* not recursive, the second function clearly is -- and that function is where the work is actually done.

Comment: Another remark: the main/original/prep function does not handle the base case. The base case is where the recursion ends (in your example  `(c==n)`) and handled by the helper function. You can remove the test  for `n==1` from the main function and just `return fibonacci(n, 1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: @nimi In tail-recursion fib you start with the base case and work up to n.

Comment: @Portaljacker: I want to disagree. The base case of a recursive function is when recursion stops. Classical fib and tail-rec fib are slightly different functions, the first goes from n to 1, the second from 1 to n, so they have different base cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would still call this "recursion." The one-argument overload of `fibonacci` is not recursive, but the 4-argument overload is recursive without a doubt.

That said: don't fool yourself into thinking that the `fibonacci` function overall is recursive. The one-argument overload never calls itself. In Java-like languages, where a function/method is uniquely defined by its signature, you still have two distinct functions.

Comment: I know, I just always feel dumb writing a multiple parameter function and writing, "Assume these variables are this, this & that and n is the Fibonacci number requested."

Comment: @Portaljacker don't forget about default arguments (if you're using C++).

Comment: Wait, what? Did not know about that! What's the syntax? I assume you can replace those values in the successive recursive calls right? What other languages support it? Most of my classwork is in Java but some is in C++ so it's good to know stuff like that!

Comment: @Portaljacker your function signature would look like `fibonacci(int n, int f1 = 2, int f2 = 1, int c = 2)`. That way, you can call it with one or more (but less than 4) arguments and the others will have their defaults, or you can call it with all of them and they will have those values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like I saw that somewhere but I was never sure if I was making it up or not. Any idea on the other languages which do it?

Comment: @Portaljacker as a rule of thumb, note that default arguments are a shorthand/shortcut for function overloading; anything that can be done with default arguments can be done with function overloading (but not necessarily the other way around). As for other languages, I know that Python and Ruby can do it (and Delphi iirc) but I don't know any others. There are undoubtedly more.

Comment: Sorry for the late question but, what is benefit of overloading a recursive function?